# Groovy SQL eachRow format output

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, grails, groovy

I have to synchronize MSSQL DB with MYSQL DB. (>500 Tables and total >10000000 lines).
I have a working solution, but the performance is not acceptable.
The bottleneck may be here:

I read from the MSSQL database with

```
mssqlDaten = mssql.eachRow (....) { row_data -> ...
```

because of the changing field names in the different tables i'm using a for loop to create the insert statement

```
    str = "insert into current_table values ("
    for (over all fields from the current table) {
    str += "'" + row_data[i] + "', "
    } 
    str += ")" 
    mssql.execute (str)
```

This may be the problem for every line i have to go thru the loop.

Has someone an idea to get the row-data directly in the format (ValueField1, ValueField2,....). When i print the row data now, i get (NameField1:ValueField1, NameField2.ValueField2,...).

Comment: could you provide schemas for source and destination tables?

Comment: the schemas are identical, because i create the tables include all fields and datatyps with the code before i start to write the data.

Comment: Can't you do something like `insert into mytable select * from mytable`, not sure how you link your schemas in mysql but in Oracle you'd have a database link so the update would be more like `insert into mytable select * from dblinked.mytable`, you could query all tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES maybe (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) then iterate over each and execute insert

Answer (score 0):

try to do insertion with batch like this:

```java
def table = "MYTABLE"
//the list of column names could be selected from source database
def columns = ["A","B","C","D"]

def sQuery = "select ${columns.join(',')} from $table".toString()

//build insert query with column list and ? as value placeholders
//as result we have query like : insert into MYTABLE ( A,B,C,D ) values ( ?,?,?,? )
def iQuery = "insert into $table ( ${columns.join(',')} ) values ( ${ columns.collect{'?'}.join(',') } )".toString()

def updateCounts = mysql.withBatch(100, iQuery) { ps ->
    mssql.eachRow (sQuery) { row_data ->
        def row_array = columns.collect{ colname-> rowdata[colname] }
        ps.addBatch( row_array )
    }
}
```

Comment: still the problem with the complexity of the different tables. First table 130 fields, second 20 fields, third 400 fields,... the insert part i can fill with the tablenames. But don't know how i can put the fieldnames at  ps.addBatch( [  here i have to place the string with the fieldnames ???   ] ).

Comment: @Helge, i've added some dynamic for query generation to example